# Looking for CART/ML model that works with relative data

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-trees, boosting, cart

I am a beginner at AI and ML. I have been given a dataset, where I have noticed the columns are relative to one another. So is there any CART or ML model that can work with relative data ?

For example in Decision Tree, the tree looks like :

```
  if X[0]<192:
     if X[1]>24:
       if X[2]<12:
       ...
```

I'm looking for a Decision Tree, that works like this :

```
  if X[0]>X[1]:
   if X[1]<X[2]:
      ...
```

Is there any such Machine Learning Model ?